# Create an update query which calculates total cost?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

So customers Buy products. some customers have contracts for individual products and pay a lower cost per unit. Im trying to create an update query which calculates the total cost by multiplying units purchased by either stock price or contract price depending. I am using phpmyadmin. I've been stuck on this for a long time any help would be greatly appreciated.

Basically i want to update total cost in my orders table besed off the details in my order_details table. I have used CASE to decide whether to multiply units by contract price or stock price.

When i run the query below i get no errors but it does not affect any rows in my table

```
    UPDATE orders 
    INNER JOIN order_details ON orders.`Order No` = order_details.OrderId 
    INNER JOIN contracts ON order_details.contractId = contracts.`Contract ID` 
    INNER JOIN stock ON contracts.`Product Code` = stock.`Product code` 
    SET orders.`total cost` = (CASE WHEN order_details.contractId = 
    contracts.`Contract ID` THEN order_details.Unitspurchased * 
    contracts.`Contract Price` ELSE order_details.Unitspurchased * stock.`Sale 
    price` END ) 
    WHERE order_details.OrderID = orders.`Order No``
```

Comment: Without seeing some data or error message, it might be hard for someone to help you here.

Comment: Shouldn't the total cost of orders be calculated when you read the data, not stored along with the data?  Seems like trying to store the same information in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an aggregation of some sort.

Second, I don't understand where the columns are really located.  I would expect `order_details` to have a product code, for instance.

I would expect a query like this:

```
UPDATE orders o
       (SELECT od.order_id,
               SUM(od.Unitspurchased * COALESCE(c.`Contract Price`, s.`Sale price`)) as total_price
        FROM order_details od JOIN
             stock s
             ON od.`Product Code` = s.`Product code` LEFT JOIN
             contracts c
             ON od.contractId = c.`Contract ID` 
        GROUP BY od.order_id
       ) od
    SET o.`total cost` = od.total_cost ;
```

For the join to contracts, you might also need:

```
ON od.contractId = c.`Contract ID` AND
   od.`Product Code` = c.`Product Code`
```

If the product is in the contract table.

I would also recommend that you fix your column names.  Having spaces means that you need to escape the names, which just makes the query harder to write and to read.